# Deleting duplicate rows beyond the second in Excel, based on a single column

Tags: excel, duplicates, delete-row

I have an Excel spreadsheet with duplicate rows, and I want to keep at most two for a given user. How can I keep two duplicate rows, then delete all the additional rows if they have the same value in column C?

Here's an example - I want to keep the two highlighted rows, but delete the rest:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb and assume you are talking about [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) since there are no application or language tags associated with your inquiry.

After selecting your data, use Data ► Data Tools ► Remove Duplicates. Choose the columns that define a duplicate value. Click OK.

Remove duplicates removed from the bottom to the top so you are left with the records that were closer to the top.

Comment: Thanks Dan and Jeeped. Have added Excel to my question.

Comment: Jeeped - thanks so much - your answer is helpful, but I want to keep two duplicate rows, not just one. We're running a competition where users can enter no more than twice. I want to keep two entried from any given user, but remove any additional entries.

Comment: Ah yes; sorry I missed that. In that case I would recommend a 'helper' column with a formula like `=COUNTIF(C$1:C1, C1)>2` then sort or filter on this column and delete all of the TRUE entries.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help.